# Cannot validate date output from date picker

Tags: javascript, textfield

I am using a small js widget called SCW for my date picker and all is working fine. Now I want to validate the date from the date picker on the event onfocusout. All works fine except that I get the initial date instead of the date just picked by the date picker. I am sort one step behind: every time I pick a new date.

In the help text of the SCW script it says:

```
// Finally you can use the following technique to run a function
//            when the calendar closes:
//
//                  scwNextAction=<<function>>.runsAfterSCW(this,<<arguments>>);
//                  scwShow(<<element>>,event <<,optional arguments above>>);
//
//            Where <<function>> is a function defined on the calling page
//            and <<arguments>> is the list of arguments being passed to that
//            function.
```

Thought it could help me, but I could not figure it out.

My code is:

```
    <input name="dato"type="text" class="ff" id="dato" tabindex="1"
  onclick="scwShow(dato,event);" value="<%=dato%>" size="12" onfocusout="tjektimereg(this.value)"/>
```

Comment: Use OnChange event of the input. In that you will get the latest value/date selected.

Comment: Unfortunately that only works if you type in the manually - when picking from the date picker SCW, the event onchange is not triggerede.....but thank you for replying.